# How to change dynamically a ListView's item  layout

Tags: android

I want to know how to change dynamically a ListView's item layout.

To be exact, i want to know the method that the ListView's bindView method is called at runtime.

if the bindView method is artificially called by a other method. then i will change a ListView's item layout.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to extend `ListAdapter` and override `getView()`

[Here is a blogpost](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/comment-page-1/) with an example.